# How to create coupon for specific SKU

Tags: magento2, coupon, sku

Magento 1.xx can easily make a coupon for specific SKU, why the SKU disappear on Magento 2.xx

Answer (score 5):

Set Attribute property:
Store->Attribute(Product)->SKU->storefront properties :

[image]

This will allow your attribute to be in list of Cart Rule -> condition.(above answer i mentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing you want.
Magento 2 also provide to generate coupon for speciafic SKU

[image]

Comment: For some reason mine does not have the SKU for choosing.

Comment: @Lightsdepot that's because you need to allow SKU rules. You can do that in Stores > Attributes > Product. Search there for `SKU`, open it, click on "Storefront Properties" tab and set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to "Yes". For more info see: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-multiple-sku.html

Answer (score -1):

There is an option in magento 2 as well to configure coupon code for a specific Sku please refer the below screen .

```
http://screencast.com/t/TqYIZlpyxzQh
```